# How do I modify static properties of a class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, immutability

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass
{

    public static $test = 'foo';

    public function example()
    {
        return Self::$test;
    }

}

// What I'm trying to do
MyClass->$test = 'bar'; 

$test = new MyClass();
echo $test->example(); // Should return `bar` instead of `foo`.
```

Is this or anything remotely close to this possible in PHP?

Comment: If you use `MyClass::$test = 'bar';` instead of `MyClass->$test = 'bar'; ` (your example is not using the static variable as you have assigned it in the class) it returns `bar`. If you specifically want to us the `->` notation instead of `::` it will not work (or, you may get a deprecation error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track you just need to access the variable as Class::$test

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $test = 'foo';

    public function example()
    {
        return Self::$test;
    }
}

MyClass::$test = 'bar'; 

$test = new MyClass();
echo $test->example(); // returns bar
```

Comment: Awesome!  I forgot that I need to use `::` operator on `static` properties. Thanks.