# Can I modify non-static properties of a class in PHP before initializing it?

Tags: php, oop, immutability

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass
{

    public $test = 'foo';

    public function example()
    {
        return $this->test;
    }

}

// What I'm trying to do
MyClass->test = 'bar'; 

$test = new MyClass();
echo $test->example(); // Should return `bar` instead of `foo`.
```

I want to modify the base Class *before* initializing it.
Is this possible to do in PHP?

(Yes, I know that modifying [static properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53879506/1454514) are possible. I'm curious about the *non-static* ones.)

Comment: Should be `$test->test = 'bar'; ` Just after you instantiate the class

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it before initializing it.

Comment: Basically you want to modify the class definition. Not sure whether it might be possible using reflection, but it's probably almost never a good idea.

Comment: I thought that was what construct was for...

Comment: You'd better talk about the original problem instead of thinking about the solution.

Comment: I agree with @revo are you trying to achieve something specific doing it that way or just wanting top know what you can or can't do in OOP?

Comment: Both actually, I need to achieve something like this one way or another; but I really do wanna have a bit deeper level understanding of OOP in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change a property's default value after the class was created. And I'm pretty sure reflection won't allow it either.

Here's what you can do instead:

```
class MyClass
{
  public static $default_test = 'foo';
  public $test;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->test = self::$default_test;
  }

  public function example()
  {
    return $this->test;
  }
}

MyClass::$default_test = 'bar';

$test = new MyClass();
echo $test->example();
```

Basically, you have a static property that holds the default value, and the constructor sets the property's initial value to it.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/djn3T**

A bit confused as to why you wouldn't just pass the value to the class' constructor, though. But you may have your reasons.

Comment: This is fine, but question clearly states Non static properties

Comment: @rs007 Right, but the end goal is to change the future objects' (non-static) property, which this does. The static property here is just a tool.

Comment: I appreciate your response using the `static` properties! As for why I don't just pass it to the constructor, the reason is that the property contains _settings_ for my class, and I don't want to introduce a secondary parameter just to pass my settings on each initialization. `$foo = new MyClass( $settings, $actual_param );` – hence why I'm curious if this is possible.

Comment: Then just pass an array as the first argument and work with that array. @DRSDavidSoft

Comment: For my application, I'd rather not to use the _dependency injection_ method. ([i.e. here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53907628/1454514))